# How to push data in list without the name of the parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm using ajax and consuming API. I need expected output as:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Meetting",
    "value": 5
  },
  {
    "label": "Offical",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "label": "Support",
    "value": 11
  }
]
```

My code:

```
var MyData = data;
let _data = [];

MyData.map(function(x) {
    let _d = {};
    _d.label = x.type;
    _d.value = x.total;
    _data.push({
        _d
    });
});
```

but my Output is:

```
[
  {
    "_d": {
      "label": "Meetting",
      "value": 5
    }
  },
  {
    "_d": {
      "label": "Offical",
      "value": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "_d": {
      "label": "Support",
      "value": 11
    }
  }
]
```

How can I remove `_d` or avoid `_d` while pushing data?

Comment: Remove the `{}` from `_data.push({_d})`. Or just do `return _d` inside the callback and `let _data = MyData.map(...)`

Answer (score -1):

You can remove `{}` from `_data.push({_d});`

So your code becomes:

```js
var MyData = data;
let _data = [];
MyData.map(function(x) {
    let _d = {};
    _d.label = x.type;
    _d.value = x.total;
    _data.push(_d);
 });
```